# Никотин(о)содержащие продукты

Tags: орфография

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно: "никотинсодержащая жидкость" или "никотинОсодержащая"? Ворд подчеркивает и тот, и тот вариант.
Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно "никотиносодержащая жидкость", хотя в текстах встречается и другой вариант. Это слово образовано стандартным методом чистого сложения, сравнить: витаминосодержащие, углесодержащие.